# How can I select models (in GLMM) when adding another factor drops some observations?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, modeling

I am having difficulty selecting models in GLMM. I am using `glmer()` of `lme4`. I would like to choose the model which provides better prediction.

```
model1 <- glmer (y ~ factor1, family = binomial, data = dat)
model2 <- glmer (y ~ factor1 + factor2, family = binomial, data = dat)
AIC (model1, model2)
anova (model1, model2)
anova (model2)
```

I firstly thought I can select models using AIC; however, I realized that adding `factor2` drops some observations because of observations lack values for `factor2`. AIC and residual are smaller for `model2`, but, any level of `factor2` is not significant. Also, `anova()` function does not provide p-values for factors when I use `glmer()`. How can I select models in such a case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any metrics that can be used to compare models with different samples.

An easy solution would be to drop the cases that aren't included from `model2` from the `dat` of `model1`. For example, let's say `factor2` has `NA` values. You could safely compare these two models:

```
model1 <- glmer(y ~ factor1,           family = binomial, data = dat[!is.na(dat$factor2), ])
model2 <- glmer(y ~ factor1 + factor2, family = binomial, data = dat[!is.na(dat$factor2), ])
anova(model1, model2, refit = FALSE)
```

---

In case you (or someone Googling in the future) is unfamiliar with the indexing I did to `dat`: `is.na()` will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` values: `TRUE` if the observation is `NA`, `FALSE` otherwise. We do that for `factor2` from `dat`. We want it to be the opposite, though (i.e., return `TRUE` if it is *not* `NA`, so we know to keep it), so I put a `!` in front for that purpose. And then I just pull the rows out of `dat` that are `TRUE` for that expression using indexing `[]`.

Comment: +1 Great answer. Another way to solve the NA values problem is to select just the variables you need from dat and then use `na.omit`, which will remove cases with missing values on any variables. For example: `data = na.omit(dat[ ,c("y", "factor1", "factor2")])`

Comment: @RoseHartman +1 for the simpler code

Comment: Thank you very much for your claer answer, @MarkWhite! As a novice R user, I really appreciate that you explained the code very much. Thank you, @RoseHartman, for your simple code as well.